# Please describe the meaning of and the mantras associated with the Parashurama Yantra

Tags: mantras, parashurama, yantra

[image]

The above is an image of the Parashurama Yantra.

Please tell me what does this mean?
What numbers are associated with this Yantra?
What musical tones or mantras are associated with this Yantra , if any?

Comment: The pattern was inside the bowl made by the the contents which were purple fruit juice and white yoghurt and it sat on a small white square table. Exactly like the picture above , which is the Parashurama Yantra.

Comment: @TheFool You exactly saw that Yantra in ur dream? BTW how could u remember that this is the one? Because i can't remember any of my dreams given that i had them (which even i can't say for sure) haha..

Comment: @TheFool And how did you know that this is called the Parashurama Yantra? Do u have previous knowledge about the Yantra?

Comment: @TheFool I have removed the personal details from ur Q. So that it can be re-opened. Feel free to change anything you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can venerate the yantra with simple kumkum or flowers or rice grain etc.

You can chant [parashurAma](http://www.sarvamantra.com/parshuram-gayatri-mantra/) gayatri mantra

परशुराम  गायत्री  मंत्र :-

ॐ  जामदग्न्याय  विद्महे  महावीराय  धीमहि  ! तन्न: परशुराम:   प्रचोदयात  !

Or

‘ॐ  रां  रां  ॐ  रां  रां  ॐ  परशुहस्ताय नम:

or simple naama mantra.

Here is a [stotra](https://www.devshoppe.com/blogs/articles/shri-parshuram-stotram-in-sanskrit) which can be used while worshiping his yantra.

श्री परशुराम स्तोत्रम्

कराभ्यां परशुं चापं दधानं रेणुकात्मजं ।
जामदग्न्यं भजे रामं भार्गवं क्षत्रियान्तकं ॥१॥

नमामि भार्गवं रामं रेणुका चित्तनन्दनं ।
मोचितंबार्तिमुत्पातनाशनं क्षत्रनाशनम् ॥२॥

भयार्तस्वजनत्राणतत्परं धर्मतत्परम् ।
गतगर्वप्रियं शूरं जमदग्निसुतं मतम् ॥३॥

वशीकृतमहादेवं दृप्त भूप कुलान्तकम् ।
तेजस्विनं कार्तवीर्यनाशनं भवनाशनम् ॥४॥

परशुं दक्षिणे हस्ते वामे च दधतं धनुः ।
रम्यं भृगुकुलोत्तंसं घनश्यामं मनोहरम् ॥५॥

शुद्धं बुद्धं महाप्रज्ञापण्डितं रणपण्डितं ।
रामं श्रीदत्तकरुणाभाजनं विप्ररंजनम् ॥६॥

मार्गणाशोषिताभ्ध्यंशं पावनं चिरजीवनम् ।
य एतानि जपेन्द्रामनामानि स कृति भवेत् ॥७॥

इति श्री प. प. श्री वासुदेवानंदसरस्वतीविरचितं श्री परशुराम स्तोत्रं संपूर्णम् ॥